# JSSOR transitions float off screen sides making scrollbars appear/disappear

Tags: jssor

I am building my first slider, Dodge Pet Outside out Random Chess and have everything as it should be. However I am using 75% viewport images making the transition blocks float off the screen sides, this causes the scroll bars to show and disappear.

Any advise on applying transitions that run off screen, and how to stop scroll-bars appearing/disappearing?

Thnx JSSOR for a great freesource slideshow! Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set 'overflow: hidden' for the parent container of Jssor Slider,

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">

    <div id="slider1_container" ...>...</div>

</div>
```

Or you can just set 'ooverflow: hidden' for Jssor Slider container.

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="overflow: hidden;" ...>...</div>
```

Comment: Hi @jssor, is there a way to add scroll bars to the thumbnail navigator?

Comment: There is no scroll bar option. I think you can create your own thumbnails outside jssor slider to reach your goal.

Comment: Sounds good thanks man. BTW, do you have a twitter I can follow?

Comment: As I am always busy, I don't even have time to update twitter. I should have a twitter account later. You are welcome!